# How do you use the framework.jar from a target system in AndroidStudio?

Tags: customization, dalvik, build, android-studio

I want to develop an application, in AndroidStudio, for a target system with a custom **/system/app/framework.jar**

The SDK for JellyBean 4.2, in **...\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-17** has an 
**android.jar** which I think is the 'framework' classes.  I want to use the framework from the target machine; which I think is in **/system/app/framework.jar**.  framework.jar of course contains **classes.dex**, the dalvik version of the java classes.  Can AndroidStudio use the dalvik code in framework.jar as the android.jar?

For example, I think that **android.media.AudioManager** and **android.media.AudioService** in the framework.jar (on the target machine) were customized and not the same as the stock SDK for JellyBean 4.2.  I want to develop an app using some of the features of the target machine.  So I'd like to tell AndroidStudio to use the real framework.jar and not the stock android.jar  I hope that AndroidStuio is smart enough to be able to get the API and classes and method signatures from a dalvik .dex file rather than from a java .jar file.  -- Or is java->dalvik a one way rat hole that requires the original java class files?

(In desparation) Perhaps I could take the classes in the framework.jar classes.dex and build an android.jar with dummy (java) classes in it that contain the classes and methods (with no code in the methods) and replace android.jar in the sdk/platform/android-17 directory.  Hopefully AndroidStudio would not need to execute anything in android.jar, just check the names and signatures.

Comment: When you say customized API on the target machine: Why can't it be third-party APIs rather than modified Android framework classes? There are tools for reverse engineering dex, but I believe you are correct about the one-way nature of the toolchain. Also android.jar on PC is just stubs, see: [What is android.jar ? What does it include?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50283073/295004)

Comment: I don't know of any specific tools that can do it, but your idea about generating a new android.jar is likely the way to go. You're correct, in that the classes in the android.jar only need to be stubs.

Comment: @MorrisonChang  By 'customized' I mean the framework.jar file from the phone contains code (or changes) by the phone developer that are different from the source from AOSP SDK files.  (Is the phone developer a second party or a third party??)  I was using JADX to decompile the framework.jar from the phone and see differences between that and the SDK API 17 source that should match the version the phone developer started with.  The fact that android.jar is just stubs means I should be able to make one that matches what is on the phone.