# What is the android.jar file?

Tags: java, android

I'm coming from web dev starting android dev, and I'm a little confused on the purpose of the `android.jar` file and its purpose. At first I thought it was the jar file containing all of the classes and implementation of the android framework for it to be bundled with our app, but according to this answer it isn't — [What is android.jar? What does it include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283073/what-is-android-jar-what-does-it-include#:%7E:text=%2C%20types%2C%20etc.-,The%20android.,on%20any%20Android%20platform%20behavior).

What dose he mean by "two android.jar files"? Can someone elaborate on his answer?

Comment: Edit: At least for me, the android SDK docs seem very vague and don't really explain what exactly each component dose, so yeah.

Comment: I believe the way it works is essentially interface vs. implementation: the android.jar lib you compile against (compile classpath) has only method stubs and is not packaged with your code, and then at runtime the device's android.jar implementation is loaded (runtime classpath) and it contains the actual framework API implementation.  I haven't found good docs proving this, however.